# Deactivate UIRefreshControl while searching

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I implemented a UIRefreshControl on a TableView and additionally, I added a searchController with a searchBar.

The search as well as the pull to refresh work perfectly fine, the only thing I'm struggling with is how to deactivate the "pull to refresh" function when the searchController is active.

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581534/swift-disable-refreshcontrol-while-searching) solution, but somehow that did not work for me.

Comment: do you want the refresh control target function not to be called or hide the refresh control

Comment: I'd like to have both. The UIRefreshcontrol should not work and it should not show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your viewcontroller conform the `UISearchBarDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate
```

and implement two of its methods

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.removeRefreshControl()        
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.initRefreshControl()
}
```

In each method call the functions to set and remove the `UIRefreshControl`

```
func initRefreshControl() {
    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData), for: .valueChanged)

    self.tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
}

func removeRefreshControl() {
    self.refreshControl = nil
}
```

The complete code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initRefreshControl()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.removeRefreshControl()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.initRefreshControl()
    }

    func initRefreshControl() {
        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData), for: .valueChanged)

        self.tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
    }

    func removeRefreshControl() {
        self.refreshControl = nil
    }

    @objc func refreshData() {
        ....
        ....
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

This should work.